# when calling a service to save the non-translated text in the ngx-translate library, but I'm wrong

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**
The error that it generates is the following Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError (AppModule) [MissingTranslationHandler -> TranslationService]:

```
export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
    private item:any;

    handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
        this.item = new PendingtranslationModule();
        this.item.literal=params.key;
        this.item.language=params.translateService.store.currentLang;
        var result
        result = this.TranslationService.save(this.item).subscribe(res => {
            if(res.isSuccess == true){
                console.log(res.isSuccess);
            }
        }, err => { console.log(err) }) ;
        console.log(result);
     }

  constructor(private TranslationService: TranslationService) {}
}


@NgModule({

    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        SharedModule,
        FuseMainModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            },
            missingTranslationHandler: {
                provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
                useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler,
                deps: [TranslationService]
            }
        }),
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        ServicesModule,
        SharedCommonModule,
        GrowlModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        LocaleTransleteService,
        SharedMainModule
    ],
    providers: [
        FuseSplashScreenService,
        FuseConfigService,
        FuseNavigationService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
```

Comment: dp upi jave MissingTranslationHandler and TranslationService declared in your module?

Comment: yes, I have imported each of them

Comment: i think it is complaining about the TranslationService I guess.  do you have that as a provider?  or maybe it needs to be forRoot provided?

Comment: add the TranslationService as providers, but the error still follows

Comment: if you can make a stackblitz link of the code I can look at it